# laspack for windows + visual studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, linear-algebra

I want to incorporate laspack into a C++ program in VS. All the downloads I've found have only a linux installer. Is there a windows installation\equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out my question wasn't very smart - I just downloaded the source files and opened a new project containing them. Everything compiled fine.